# How to change <div> class using php?

Tags: php, html

how can i change a  class using PHP?

```
<div class="divcss red-bg">
```

to

```
<div class="divecss blue-bg">
```

I'm using a config file and want to add the code there so i can change the div-backgrounds on all pages without extra code in any file.

I already tried to work with preg_replace but didnt get it yet

```
preg_replace('/class="divecss red-bg"/', 'class="divecss blue-bg"');
```

**Best Regards, GangstaSunny.**

Comment: Couldn't you just change the class to 'my-bg' and change the background color in your css (I believe that's what external style-sheets are for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a config file, when you reload the page that you want to change the class from, all you have to do is add inline php to change the tag.

So first grab what you want the class to be that's stored in your database or where ever the data is saved.

Assign it to a variable, lets say maybe - $config-bg .  $config-bg could store red-bg, blue-bg, black-bg, whatever you have css built for.

Then just echo the variable where you need it to change by doing this.

`<div class="divecss <?php echo $config-bg; ?>">`

Comment: Well that isnt what i wanted cuz i dont want to change all the code in my files. Any other solution maybe?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Once you change the code, you only have to change it in one place should you want to change it again and possibly add other classes; similar to putting your nav bar in a separate class and including it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure what you are trying to di, but you are missing a parameter in you code. It should be:

```
preg_replace('/class="divecss red-bg"/', 'class="divecss blue-bg"', $html);
```

Where you have the HTML code in the `$html` var. You may need [ob_get_clean](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-get-clean.php) if you are already running the script.

Hope this help =)